# Can't return factorial result in tailrec function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm practicing recursion in Kotlin and decided to create a factorial function

```
fun fact(x:Int):Int{

    tailrec fun factTail(y:Int, z:Int=1) : Int{

        if (x == 0) {return z}
        else if (x == 1) {return z}
        else {
            return factTail(y-1, y*z)
        }

    }

return factTail(x,1)
```

I'm simply calling this function in main:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

println("5! is ${fact(5)}")

}
```

I don't get any errors but I can't see the result neither.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (x == 0) {return z}
else if (x == 1) {return z}
```

These checks should be against `y` instead of `x`, `x` is the parameter of the outer `fact` function and never changes :)

You get no errors or crashes because the infinite recursive calls get optimized to an infinite loop.